# Interpretation of sentence in introduction of “When we were very young”

Tags: meaning, sentence

I've been reading **When We Were Very Young** by *A.A.Milne* and stumbled upon this sentence in the Introduction, when the author raises the topic of who is “saying” the verses in the volume of poems:

> I don't know if you have ever met **Hoo**, but he is one of those curious
> children who **look four on Monday**, and **eight on Tuesday**, and **are really
> twenty-eight on Saturday**; and you never know whether it is the day
> when **he can pronounce his 'r's'**.

I marked in bold those parts I don't really understand.

Is **Hoo** just another way of saying **Who**? What does it mean **look four on Monday**, **eight on Tuesday**, **twenty-eight on Saturday**? And finally, what does it mean **he can pronounce his 'r's'**?

Comment: Exactly what it says.  On Mondays he looks like he's 4 years old, and he looks older on Tuesdays.  Some days he can pronounce words with "r" in them, other days he can't.

Comment: I still don't get the idea of saying this. To me there's no logic in this. Maybe it's because English is my second language and for native speakers the meaning here is obvious.

Comment: What is illogical about it?

Comment: Everything. The whole sentence has no sense to me. I mean, how is that possible what is written in that sentence? To me those are just random numbers, days of the week and that 'r' thing... Maybe I'm just too old for this. I don't know.

Comment: I rather think this question lies in the realms of literary interpretation, rather than English per se. And, of course, there is some social context. But hoo can say?

Comment: Welcome! This question would be a better fit at [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/), which is a good place for the kind of questions that non-fluent speakers face regularly. Give me a second and I think I can explain, though, with a little more context...

Comment: >> "Exactly what it says" and then goes on to include a whole bunch of stuff that wasn't *exactly* said

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks for interpretation of literary devices rather than technical English. Suitable for Literature.SE IMO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A.A. Milne's writing style is charming and childlike, but he frequently "breaks" conventions of grammar and usage for his own whimsical purposes, and often comes at points obliquely. Here is a larger quote for context (from [this copy](https://www.google.com/books/edition/When_We_Were_Very_Young/gcIqAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover)):

> You may wonder sometimes who is supposed to be saying the verses. Is it the Author, that strange but uninteresting person, or is it Christopher Robin, or some other boy or girl, or Nurse, or Hoo? ... If you are not quite sure, then it is probably Hoo. I don't know if you have ever met Hoo, but he is one of those curious children who look four on Monday, and eight on Tuesday, and are really twenty-eight on Saturday, and you never know whether it is the day when he can pronounce his "r's." He has a great deal to do with these verses. In fact, you might almost say that this book is entirely the unaided work of Christopher Robin, Hoo, and Mr. Shepard, who drew the pictures.

The first thing that emerges is that *Hoo* is an intentional, humorous misspelling of *who*. The construction "Is it X, or Y, or who?" means "or some other person." Milne then doubles down on this flight of fancy by personifying this new "Hoo" character. The material that follows is honestly confusing and coy, and one must piece together a total by inference. But the "four on Monday and eight on Tuesday" might be a reference to children's ability to act or appear unusually mature for their age at one moment, and quite childlike at another (or perhaps it's just adults' ability to project these notions onto children). This is especially true at certain times of transition in childhood development. The part about pronouncing *r*s is clearly about the speech imperfections common in young children; by suggesting that it's inconsistent, Milne again points at a period of transition.

If that were all, we might suppose that the sentence was merely an indulgent observation about how quickly and unpredictably children grow up. But Milne offers another clue when he says the book is the "work of Christopher Robin, Hoo, and Mr. Shepard." Christopher Robin helped by providing inspiration, and E.H. Shepard provided the pictures. It is reasonable to suppose, then, that by suggesting that the remainder is "Hoo," Milne means to identify this changeable "spirit of childhood" in his own self, and to suggest that his inner, unpredictable child is reflected in his writing.

Comment: I thought I was going to read some childish poems and would easily grasp everything, but I was very wrong. This is very deep and very beautiful. It's like the whole new world for me to explore. I picked Milne, because 'Winnie the Pooh' is my favorite fairy-tale from the childhood but back then I read it in my native language, of course. I hope I'll be able to read the whole collection of 4 books and appreciate it the way native English speakers do. Thank you very much for your time and your amazing and detailed explanation of the matter.

Comment: I wonder if the pronouncing 'r's is less to do with speech imperfections and more to do with rolling your 'r's as practised further north.  I wonder this because I can't think of a speech imperfection involving 'r' pronunciation (except perhaps the transliteration of 'r' and 'l' supposedly common in Asian speakers of English).

Comment: @mcalex - Some children, and even a few adults, pronounce 'r' like 'w'. (the broadcaster Jonathan Ross is sometimes known as Wossy because he makes his own name sound like 'Woss'.) There's also the famous review of another A.A. Milne book by Dorothy Parker, writing under the name of 'Constant Reader', in which she said (mimicking childish speech) "Tonstant Weader fwowed up".

Comment: Of course, memory completely failed me.  Pilate (and Biggus) in Monty Python's Life of Brain would be my go-to.    :-D

Answer (score 4):

For what it‘s worth, my own interpretation of this passage is that different poems in the volume are pitched at different levels — from that of a naïve child of four years old to an adult of 28. The reference to pronouncing ‘r’s possibly relates to a speech imperfection of young children (perhaps his own son) which would not be found in a more mature individual, reinforcing the range of the different poems with a personal touch (which may not be to everyone’s liking).

But read the poems. And read them to your children.

Comment: This is beautiful. Thank you, David. I've never read too many poems actually, mostly prose. Maybe that is the reason why it's hard for me to understand those metaphors. From now on I'm gonna start reading more poems and will try to understand them better.

Comment: @JConstantine That's a great idea, but be warned that you can't always expect poetry to abide by the rules of standard language (that's in some ways its point). Also, by all means read all the works of A.A. Milne, but be warned that there are many intentional non-standard spellings and usages, meant to be whimsical.